# Ubuntu 16.04 Apache update configuration reset

Tags: apt, apache2

I have Ubuntu 16.04 with  Apache/2.4.18 that I want to update to a higher version using ppa and `apt upgrade`. Does upgrading the package this way cause its configuration files to be reset/overwritten to defaults? In other words, since I have PHP-FPM module enabled instead of the default mod_php and mpm_event instead of the default mpm_prefork, will I have to make those changes again if I perform the upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regularly you get a request which configuration files you want to keep during that process, so that is interactive. In your case you should choose `N` to keep your current configuration files instead of installing the package maintainers version.

Comment: So just to be sure, there are some packages that do not ask whether I want to keep the configuration files and just proceed to overwrite them?

Comment: php, and apache ask for sure. And since you're only updating apache the rest should stay the same.